# Magento 2: How to use ElasticSearch?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, autocomplete

I'm new to Magento 2. I want to use ElasticSearch as a search engine and also for autocomplete for Magento.

How can I do this?

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks?

Answer (score 7):

We have been using https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite with some good success. It does come with some other functionality as well as search but it's well maintained.

Comment: instructions here: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/wiki/ServerConfig-6.x

Comment: I have checked this module but look like this also not providing data directly from elasicsearch, this extension also include catalog product model collection and then return the data to api response. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most direct answer is to **buy Enterprise** - I don't see any extensions listed in Magento Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Elasticsearch for Magento 2 by Wyomind](https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/elastic-search-magento.html).

First, you will need to install and enable Elasticsearch on your web server. The module supports Elasticsearch version from 2.x to 5.x. To install the Elasticsearch, check out this official link:

https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch

After installing and enabling ES on your web server, just install the above said Elasticsearch module on your Magento 2.x store and you are ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

I have already installed the elasitcsearch in my system. My requirement is when we load products on category page using graphql api of default magento.

Those products come from catalog model connection + elasticsearch combination, instead of that, I directly want data from elasticsearch.

So can you please guide me in that way.

Thanks